# How to add duplicate element by jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

**HTML:**

```
<input type="file" name="data[Tolet][images][]"  class="span12 tolet_img" id="file" style="width:100%;"/>
```

I want to add duplicate element on click 'tolet_img' class.

I tried as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tolet_img').click(function(){
        var htmlString = $(this).clone();
        $(this).after(htmlString);
    });    
});
```

I expect after one click html will be:

```
<input type="file" name="data[Tolet][images][]"  class="span12 tolet_img" id="file" style="width:100%;"/> 
<input type="file" name="data[Tolet][images][]"  class="span12 tolet_img" id="file" style="width:100%;"/>
```

But it does not work. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Works fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/v5uyrjtx/)!

Comment: Its working as expected https://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/nv3syj97/

Comment: were you expecting cloning to happen from newly added elements as well ? https://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/nv3syj97/1/

Comment: maybe you should pass `true` to the cloning method to [clone the attributes as well](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)

Comment: Yes. I just inspect element and it is created but hide by default. Trying to showing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this:

```
var htmlString = $(this).clone(true);
```

The parameter `true` implies that the events attached to the element will also be copied. Else the cloned inputs will not perform the steps defined by the event (as its not attached by default).

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/obajqkfj/)

Comment: great! Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

It works as expected but I suggest binding the event like that

`$(document).on('click', '.tolet_img', function () {
        var htmlString = $(this).clone();
        $(this).after(htmlString);
    });`

so copied `file upload` could fire the event also

here you are a [working snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamed_badr/nv3syj97/2/)